# `nicematrix` does not update successfully to v6.4

Tags: miktex, nicematrix

I am using a MiKTeX distribution for LaTeX. I tried to check for updates to download `nicematrix` v6.4. However, the update is not really visible (i.e., even tough I have v6.3, MiKTeX console does not recognize that v6.4 is available). I tried to download the contents of the package in a zip file then run nicematrix.dtx with XeLaTeX, but I get the following message

> Runaway argument? {293574  ! File ended while scanning use of
> \pgfsyspdfmark. 
> \par  l.104 \begin{document}
> ?

Running any of the previous files which use `nicematrix` environment still works well.

Comment: miktex doesn't update every day but the update will come. Can't you simply wait until it provides version 6.4?

Comment: 6.4 is only dated a couple of days ago, it relies on unpaid human activity to copy it from ctan into miktex and texlive distribution sources and then a day or so to reach all mirrors. It is hardly surprising you do not see it yet

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am just a normal user of LaTeX. I do not really get to know a lot of details as to how packages are updated in CTAN

Comment: well as normal user: simply check for updates and don't get nervous. It can take 1-3 weeks for miktex after a package reached ctan. Your nicematrix update came today.